# Can't figure out why Height:100%; is not working

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am currently creating a section of my website for mobile. I am trying to make a section that is 100vh (which is working fine) and has two components inside of it, taking 50% each of the 100vh div by setting their height to 50% (which is working fine).

Inside the second child div is a slideshow component. The slide show component's height is set to 100% and it is currently working fine taking up the full height of its parent. However inside this slide show component is a div that has a background image. I was expecting that setting this div to 100% aswell would make it take up 100% of the slideshow components height.... But it doesn't. The only way I can change the height of the div inside the slideshow component is using px sizing. I don't understand why this is happening.

code below-

App.js

```
<div className="sh-box">
    <LargeImage />
    <SlideShow className="h-100" />
</div>
```

App.css

```
.sh-box{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
```

SlideShow.js

```
<div className="slide-container-boxed">
    <Slide {...properties} className="h-100">
        {slideImages.map((each, index) => (
        <div key={index} className="each-slide-boxed">
            <div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${each})` }}>
                <span>Slide {index + 1}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        ))}
    </Slide>
</div>
```

SlideShow.css-

```
.slide-container-boxed {
    width: 90%;
    padding: 0;
    height: 50%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color:green;
}
.each-slide-boxed{
    height:100%;
}
.each-slide-boxed > div {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.each-slide-boxed span {

    padding: 1px;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: center;

}
```

Comment: It fills 100% of its parent element's width. If the containing parent doesn't also have 100% height, then 0px IS 100% height.

Comment: The containing parent does have 100% height though. It's parent is each-slide-boxed which has height: 100% in the CSS file. Each-slide-boxed containing parent is the Slide element which has the h-100 class name.